# Putting button on bottom of my last bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a hard time aligning my button to the bottom of "login_password"
I've tried endOf and it didn't work at all and align at bottom of parent and none of it seemed to work. I've tried using margin to move it to the bottom but it just breaks the username textbox. Are there any solutions for the problem I'm experiencing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/myBlue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.vice.jake.ric.fads.view.activites.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/relativelayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logov3_4" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout2">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_outline_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:padding="16dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
            android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:padding="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_redirect_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/holo_red_light"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/login_password"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Don't have an Account? Create one!"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">




        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"

            android:src="@drawable/places_ic_search" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/places_ic_clear"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:padding="16dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/places_ic_clear"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:padding="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_redirect_register"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/login_password"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="REGISTER"
                android:textColor="#ff00" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Don't have an Account? Create one!"
            android:textColor="#ff00" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Use Linear Layout(orientation- vertical) with weight when working for Login screen so that it fits fine to all the screen sizes

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/logov3_4" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></View>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_outline_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:padding="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:padding="16dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_redirect_register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"></View>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Don't have an Account? Create one!"
        android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logov3_4" />


</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout2">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_outline_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:padding="16dp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:padding="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_redirect_register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/login_password"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />

</>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Don't have an Account? Create one!"
        android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`android:layout_below`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_below) instead of **`android:layout_toEndOf`**.

> Positions the top edge of this view below the given anchor view ID.
>   Accommodates top margin of this view and bottom margin of anchor view.

```
 android:layout_below="@id/"
```

**Finally**

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button_redirect_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/holo_red_light"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_password"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use layout_below to align button below the password field..I have reformatted your code to add that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightBlue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.vice.jake.ric.fads.view.activites.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/relativelayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_about" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout2">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_outline_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:padding="16dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
            android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:padding="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_redirect_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/holo_red_light"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_password"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Don't have an Account? Create one!"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f6faf7"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/relativelayout1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_username"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                    android:hint="Username"
                    android:padding="16dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:padding="16dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_redirect_register"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/login_password"
                    android:text="REGISTER" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Don't have an Account? Create one!" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And your output like this..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/second_container_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/card_linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp">




                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/relativelayout1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
                        android:id="@+id/relativelayout1">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                             />


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:id="@+id/relativelayout2">


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/login_username"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_outline_black_24dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                        android:hint="Username"
                        android:padding="16dp" />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/login_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:padding="16dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_redirect_register"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/holo_red_light"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/login_password"
                        android:text="REGISTER"
                        android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </ScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pay_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Don't have an Account? Create one!"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below XML Code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/myBlue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.vice.jake.ric.fads.view.activites.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/relativelayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logov3_4" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout2">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_outline_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:padding="16dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
            android:background="@drawable/luxx_edittext"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:padding="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_redirect_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/holo_red_light"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_password"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Don't have an Account? Create one!"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

You will get below output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are aligning the button to the endOf which means right side of the edittext. You have to align below the edittext layout as below

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button_redirect_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_password"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />
```

So u should be able to see the button below the login_password